# How to automatically fill pre-existing database entries with a UUID in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have added a UUID to the following model:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    ...
```

But there already are entries in the database that were created without the `uuid` field.
When I run `migrate`, it adds the same UUID to all my previous objects.

Is there an easy way of populating the existing objects with a different UUID automatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the easiest way to fix this is to make a [*data migration* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). You create a new migration file with:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty yourappname
```

This will create a new file in the `migrations/` directory that does nothing. We can alter that migration file with something that looks like:

```
# Generated by Django 3.2 on 2021-05-01 12:49

from django.db import migrations
from uuid import uuid4

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    def populate_uuid(apps, schema_editor):
        Post = apps.get_model('yourappname', 'Post')
        posts = list(Post.objects.all())
        for post in posts:
            post.uuid = uuid4()
        Post.objects.bulk_update(posts, ['uuid'])

    dependencies = [
        ('yourappname', 'previous_migrationname'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(populate_uuid)
    ]
```

If you then migrate, it will load all `Post` objects, provide these each a unique uuid, and then update the items in bulk.