# Django UUID Field does not autocreate with new entry

Tags: python, django

I just added a new model where I want to use a UUID for the first time.
I run Django 3.1.3 on python 3.8.10.

Found some questions about this and I am quite certain I did it according to those suggestions. However, when I add an entry to that model (in phpmyadmin web-surface) the UUID is not being added, it just stays empty. However when I create an other one I get the error, that the UUID Field is not allowed to be the same as somewhere else (both empty) which means at least the unique=True does work.

Another thing to mention is, when I create the field using VSCode, normally those fieldnames are being auto-completed, however it is not the case with this one. Thought this might give you a hint what is going on.

My model looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
import uuid


class MQTTTable(models.Model):
    
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key = True, default = uuid.uuid4, editable = False, unique = True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length= 100, default = None)
    clientID = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = None)
    mastertopic = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default = None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `default = uuid.uuid4` is a Django ORM default, it's not something the database will do for you like the auto incrementing for `ID`. So if you add an entry via the phpmyadmin, it will not set the uuid field.

Comment: So only if I create an entry via Django this will auto insert an UUID? Is there a way to make that happen tho?

Comment: Depends on your backend, bur for mysql the UUIDField is just a `varchar` with no default or extra. So no, it won't fill in UUID for you. Postgres has some more elaborate fields I think, but no direct experience with that. Perhaps you can set something up via phpmyadmin, but why you'd use php when you got Django I don't know. You have the Django `admin`, which will fill in the uuid if you add an entry. So use that? :)

Comment: Personally, I'd setup the Django admin and use that over phpmyadmin. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: thanks a lot! working with this for half a year, always use the phpmyadmin panel to populate with some test entries.

Comment: I understand :) But can use django admin for that as well, or if you want to use some command line you can use the shell https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#shell. Via which you can do `MQTTTable.objects.create(description='Test', clientID='foo', mastertopic='bar')`, to create objects in the DB. The UUID has a default, so don't need to set that.

Answer (score 0):

You will be needing to make migration like this in order to populate the fields for existing entries. Visit this to learn how to do that. With creation of new objects the field is auto populated using the python way. Thanks
[Migrations that add unique fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/writing-migrations/#:%7E:text=Migrations%20that%20add%20unique%20fields&text=Modify%20the%20respective%20field%20according,Run%20the%20makemigrations%20command.)

You can visit this question which may help you with your answer:
[Automatically fill pre-existing database entries with a UUID in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67344378/how-to-automatically-fill-pre-existing-database-entries-with-a-uuid-in-django)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33294710)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't add an entry in the php admin panel and expect that django adds the UUID, because it is sets by Django and not by the database. You can try to implement a function in the model.py file and serialize it as source of a Charfield, however in this case you need django rest framework

Answer (score -4):

change `default = uuid.uuid4` to `default = uuid.uuid4()`